# Is not allowed to commit file with extension .tag

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

I wanna to commit to Subversion a file with extension `.tag` (it is a tag description for jsp),
but I get:

```
Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 1) with output: "Commits prohibited in to tags!".

SVN error code is E165001.
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: from the message of the pre-commit hook i would say you are not allowed to commit to the path named `tags` not matter what the extension is, or can you commit other filetyle in the same location? anyways you need talk to the person who set that hook up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [*pre-commit hook*](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html) is something that is manually / specially added by the administrator of an svn repository to add desired functionality.  In this case, they have specifically blocked the type of commit you are trying to do.  Speak with your administrator / read information for the repository you are using etc...

Answer (score 2):

Ask your system administrator to fix the pre-commit hook script that is set on the repository. It seems that the hook script is too simple and rejects anything that has `tag` in its name.